# Javascript array with properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

Ok, so i don't understand what this means, in chrome console's I got this :

[image]

Now why is the cat4 property an Array of 0 element but has properties cat5 ? Here is what i get with JSON.stringify() :

```
{
    "cat0": [
        {
            "category": "cat0",
              ----...other properties here ...----
        }
    ],
    "cat4": [],
    "cat7": []
}
```

Comment: possibly the prototype of Array has been modified

Comment: @njzk2 No, or the other arrays would have the same property. A property has just been added to that specific array (see answer below).

Comment: @dystroy : all those arrays seem to have a "categoryName" property, but it is true that I did not see the cat5 in cat4 array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a property to an array, as it's an object :

```
var a = [];
a.name = "value";
console.dir(a); // you see name:value when you open the tree
```

but when `JSON.stringify` serializes it as JSON, those properties are ignored because the stringification of an array is specific : The [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says that arrays are to be stringified in JSON as the sequence of their elements (see 2.3). The actual implementation of `JSON.stringify` is now browser dependent but you can see the test in the [old Crockford's code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L294) :

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {
```